# Determining the percentage of the query of an alignment from a BLAST output

Tags: bioinformatics, sequence-alignment, blast

Given this BLAST output, how can I determine the percentage of the query sequence in the alignment? I know that it's also referred to as 'query cover' but I can't seem to find anything online that tells me how to calculate this.

[image]

I have given it a go and valued it as 145/147, but I'm not too sure on this. Can anybody clarify whether or not this is correct? Any help is highly appreciated

Comment: Please don't post images of text. Instead, use the [formatting tools](http://biolofy.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) and add the text directly into your question. That way, we can copy it and test our answers. Also, since this is essentially a scripting question, please clarify what operating system you are using so we know what type of answer to provide. I assume you realize that your output shows that residues 4 through 146 of a 146aa query are aligned, right?

Comment: `qcovs` and `qcovshsp` are reported.. In standalone BLAST you can specify the output format too

Comment: How can I do it without using BLAST? Just by looking at this output.